# NSTimer called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

timer inside init method calling itself twice after its interval of 10seconds.Can anybody please tell me how to stop this ? Thanks in advance.

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(serviceCalling) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //[timer fire];

    //NSDefaultRunLoopMode
    //[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
  }
  return self;
}

-(void)serviceCalling{
  NSLog(@"Inside");
}
```

Comment: if you ask stop timer [timer invalidate] should work if it's not please explain what you need.

Comment: From where are you calling the init method ? Is it happening on the main thread?

Comment: @grhnkdlk i want it to run only once after 10second interval as currently it runs immediately twice after its interval,

Comment: @WarrenBurton init is constructor of singleton class,+ (id)sharedManager {
    
    static NotificationObserver *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
        
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  Please put a breakpoint in `serviceCalling` and check the call stack to see what called it; it's possible you are calling it from somewhere unexpected by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Are you constructing this object more than once?  Given the code you have posted, that's the only explanation (unless you are confusing the repeated one 10 seconds later).

Put an NSLog in the init.

Comment: How would you construct an object more than once?

Comment: calling `[[YourClass alloc] init]` multiple times.  Did you put an NSLog in init?  You should get one serviceCalling call every 10 seconds for each init call.

Comment: @LouFranco init is constructor of singleton class,+ (id)sharedManager { static NotificationObserver *sharedMyManager = nil; static dispatch_once_t onceToken; dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init]; }); return sharedMyManager; }

Comment: Did you put an NSLog in init? Do the two "Inside" logs happen right after each other? Do you log "Inside" from more than one place?